# 64 bit windows - do I need to use IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to read some processes' PE headers in a windows 64 environment and since my code is working just by reading the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure for both 32 and 64 bit executables, I was wondering: do I need to write something like

```
if executable is 64 bit
 use IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64
else
 use IMAGE_NT_HEADERS
```

? My code seems to work by just using IMAGE_NT_HEADERS for both 64 and 32 bit processes, am I missing something?

Comment: `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is already a macro that will automatically choose between `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32` and `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64`. But yeah, basically the only difference between those structures is the size of pointers. There are properties that mess with memory addresses that are 32-bit across both platforms, those are specified as `DWORD` (even though they should be pointers really) to maintain this coherence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the difference is in some fields of OptionalHeader. For example ImageBase of 64-bit version is 64-bit size. If your code don't use any fields after `ImageBase` (including) - your code will pass tests.